# Normalization and 3NF

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization

Say I have this table, where Pizza Code is the primary key

[image: pizza table]

Is this table in 3NF? If I change the Pizza Name, then surely the Price would be affected. But at the same time, I can see that this dependency is isolated, so my question was:

1. With the current data structure, where the dependencies of
   Name/Price are isolated in a separate table, can we say that this
   table is in 3NF?
2. If the 2 non-key table columns were part of a larger, say, "Orders"
   table, then the Orders table wouldn't be in 3NF, right?

Comment: Correct. Only store the pizzacodes in the orders table.

Comment: You are probably looking for a slowly changing dimension, so the name and price can change over time for a given code.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself which is the *meaning* of PizzaCode in your table:

1. It is just a way of abbreviating the name (as it seems from the current values)?  In other words, is the operation of changing the name (and price) of a pizza something that can be thought of as a insertion of a new kind of pizza in place of an old one?
2. It is used to identify uniquely a certain object (the *same* object), that can change sometime the name and/or the price?

In the first case, just get rid of it, and use PizzaName as primary key (and as foreign key in the Order table). The operation of changing the name of the pizza and its price will be equivalent to the addition of a new pizza and the removal of the old one (or simply you can mark the old one with an attribute available/not available if you want to keep track of all the pizzas ever sold).

In the second case, use the PizzaCode as primary key and as foreign key in a table Order.